# Not able to connect from inside container, but able to connect from host

Tags: docker, networking, containers, grpc, alpine-linux

I am facing a peculiar situation, could not find much help from web.
I have a container(based on alpine image) running on Centos7 host in host network mode which essentially means it shares the network stack, /etc/hosts, and /etc/resolv.conf with host.

Trying to connect to a remote machine(UB1804-MN1-131) within our organization network (so no proxy needed). The connect call is a grpc.dial(hostname:port, ..) call.
I keep getting the below error:

```
code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: i/o timeout"
```

This behavior itself is not consistent. For e.g. it connects successfully after few retries sometimes, other times it simply refuses to connect

The same remote machine connects without any issues when tried from host itself.

Any help in finding the root cause is much appreciated. For reference, sharing eth details, host and resolv details (Edited some values in it for security reasons):

```
[user@HOST-21343-135 ~]# ip add
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9e:7c:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.65.135/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9e:12:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: ens256: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9e:23:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:b0:fa:05:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.190.64.1/25 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[user@HOST-21343-135 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 HOST-21343-135
172.17.65.131   UB1804-MN1-131

[root@ATLAS-21343-135 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
nameserver 14.110.135.81
nameserver 14.110.135.82
nameserver 14.110.135.83
```

I have verified all the above data is shared by container also.

Comment: To help isolate the issue, consider using  (a) a different distro to build the client container (perhaps Debian rather than Alpine; (b) gRPCurl there's a container version (also based on Alpine): https://hub.docker.com/r/fullstorydev/grpcurl

Answer (score 0):

After much effort, found the root cause. It was due to the DNS IPs present in /etc/resolv.conf. When I removed all DNS entries, it worked like charm. So it looks like it was routing the connection through the DNS servers and it was failing.
What I don't understand though is, the same thing works fine on the host machine with DNS present which means it ignores the DNS and only reads from /etc/hosts. However the same thing from within container did not ignore DNS entries. I am not sure why this differing behaviour, I do not know.

For now, the workaround mentioned above works for me. So I am good to go.